# Subspaces of a functional space

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $(V,\,\oplus,\,\odot)$ is a vector space where $V$ is the set of all functions $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and the operations $\oplus$ and $\odot$ are defined by $$f\oplus g = x\mapsto f(x)+g(x)\quad\text{and}\quad \lambda\odot f=x\mapsto \lambda f(x),$$

Which of the following subsets of $V$ form subspaces of $(V,\,\oplus,\,\odot)$ under the given operations?

\begin{align}
(i)&\, A=\{f\in V\colon f(3)=0\},\\
(ii)&\,B=\left\{f\in V\colon \int^{1}_{0}f \ {\rm d}x=3\right\},\\
(iii)&\,C=\text{the set of all polynomials from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with non-zero constant term},\\
(iv)&\,D=\{x\mapsto ax+b\sqrt{x}+c\colon a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}\},\\
(v)&\,E=\left\{f\in V\colon \int^{1}_{0} f\ {\rm d}x=0\right\},\\
(vi)&\,F=\{f\in V\colon \forall x\in\mathbb{R}\,\, f(x)\ge 0\}.
\end{align}

My answers are:

\begin{align}
(i)&\, \text{True.} \\
(ii)&\, \text{False, does not contain the zero vector.} \\
(iii)&\, \text{False, does not contain the zero vector.} \\
(iv)&\, \text{True if $a=b=c=0$, false otherwise since it does not contain the zero vector.} \\
(v)&\, \text{True.}\\
(vi)&\, \text{False, not closed under scalar multiplication.}
\end{align}

Are these correct?

Comment: (iv) is a little odd because $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is only defined for $x \ge 0$. Otherwise this would be a subspace. It is the collection of all functions of that form with $a,b,c$ arbitrary. That certainly includes $a=b=c=0$.

Comment: Ah ok so it is a subspace for every $x\ge0$, can you quickly show me how it includes the zero vector then? Thanks!

Comment: “Which of the following subsets of $\color{red}{\mathbb{R}}$ form subspaces...” should be $\color{blue}V$, no?

Comment: $D$ is the collection of functions of the form $x \mapsto ax+ b \sqrt{x} +c$ with $a,b,c$ arbitrary. Since $0 = 0x+ 0 \sqrt{x} +0$, the zero function is certainly in $D$ (choose the specific case of $a=b=c=0$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All yours answers are looking good for me. The only thing I want to point out is in item $({\rm iv})$: when I first read it, I understood that the set was all the functions of the form $ax+b\sqrt{x} + c$, where $a,b,c$ aren't fixed, I mean, $0$ would be there since: $$0 = 0\,x+0\,\sqrt{x}+0,$$ and this would be closed since $$a_1x+b_1\sqrt{x}+c_1+\lambda(a_2x+b_2\sqrt{x}+c_2) = (a_1+\lambda a_2)x+(b_1+\lambda b_2)\sqrt{x} + (c_1+\lambda c_2),$$ so the answer would be "yes". But if $a,b$ and $c$ are fixed, your answer there is also correct.